# Browser incompatibility Svelte

Tags: browser, svelte

I have an application in Svelte that only works on versions above 84 of chrome, but I need it to work on older versions as well. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? As in, what error do you get? Are things rendering incorrectly? You're going to have to add more details.

Comment: Apparently the errors happen in some components of the svelte. But I also identified an error on the login page, it doesn't log in and the field masks don't work either.

Comment: As H.B. has also pointed out, we cannot help you if you don't post your error message. Just saying something doesn't work on some components and another error in a login page and how everything is unpredictable doesn't make sense to us when we neither have the code nor the error messages. Not all svelte applications are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your build system and what the source of the problem is.

E.g. Vite has [built-in support](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-target) for transpiling to specific JS versions. However, if an API is missing, you have to add polyfills (e.g. via [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js)).

Comment: I tried to follow the Vite documentation you sent me. I did it like this in my vite.config.js:  build: {
  target: 'chrome80'
 }

Comment: You may also have to set `target` in [`optimizeDeps.esbuildOptions`](https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options.html#optimizedeps-esbuildoptions).

Comment: I tried to set the 'target' in 'optimizeDeps.esbuildOptions'. But it didn't work. I tried to use the plugin '@vitejs/plugin-legacy', but when I tried to run the build it gave an error in the manifest.json file

Comment: People will not be able to give you any more specific advice unless you provide information about your errors. (See also SSBakh's comment.)

Comment: Apparently the errors happen in some components of the svelte. But I also identified an error on the login page, it doesn't log in and the field masks don't work either.

Comment: That is useless, what are the actual errors?

Comment: The whole svelte system becomes unpredictable, everything starts to bug.